# Possible to get current user's account SID in Wix?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

In our installer, we pass a unique local account identifier on a service's command line, e.g.

```
<ServiceInstall ...
                Arguments="[LogonUser]"
                ... />
```

I'm considering passing the current user's account SID (e.g. S-1-5-21-4291167501-1931063052-1968030807-1001) instead.

I inherited this installer, and I'm very new to Wix. Does anyone know whether the **SID** is available, or how I might retrieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`UserSID built-in property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/usersid).